# Divide digits from a number into array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I want to put all the digits of a number into an array. Per example I have 2017 and I want a vector V = [2, 0, 1, 7]. Here is the code:

```
import array
    n = 2017
    sizeN = 4 
    m = n
    i = 1
    V = []
    while m!=0:
        V.insert((sizeN-i), (m%10))
        m = m // 10
        i+=1
    
    print(V)
```

But the problem is that V = [2, 7, 0, 1]. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` function

```
In [21]: y = 2017

In [22]: list(map(int, str(y)))
Out[22]: [2, 0, 1, 7]
```

To modify your code
Method 1:

```
n = 2017
m = n

V = []
while m:
    V.append(m%10)
    m = m // 10

V.reverse()
print(V)
```

Method 2:

```
n = 2020
m = n

V = []
while m:
    V.insert(0,m%10)
    m = m // 10

print(V)
```

Answer (score 1):

The index of location to insert is wrong.

In line 8: `V.insert((sizeN-i), (m%10))`, the first arg `index` should always be `0`, which means you should always insert the new digit to the **front**.

Changing this line to `V.insert(0, (m % 10))` will solve your problem.

To get a deeper view, we can take it step by step:

- m % 10 = 7, V = [7]
- m % 10 = 1, V = [1, 7]
- m % 10 = 0, V = [0, 1, 7]
- m % 10 = 2, V = [2, 0, 1, 7]

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, more pythonic

```
n = 2017
v = [int(d) for d in str(n)]
print(v)
```

Alternatively we can do

```
n = 2017
zero = ord('0')
v = [ord(d)-zero for d in str(n)]
print(v)
```

Both produce

```
[2, 0, 1, 7]
```

Nota Bene:
`v` is a **list**, not an array.

Please name your variables in lowercase, respecting [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)